# Performance difference between DB count and Array count

Tags: php, mysql

I hope this doesn't sound too petty and cause opinionated answers.

On my page I've already queried my database for some values with counts and stored them in an array for formatting later on my page. The `topicCount` is a count of articles posted in each topic.

```
topicName     | topicCount
--------------|-------------
Latest News   | 101
Events        | 273
...
```

I've now decided to display a count for all articles. Now, this is what I was going to do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS articleCount FROM blogArticles
$articleCount = $row['articleCount'];
```

But I'm now curious whether running a count on my array would be quicker and/or less expensive, seeming as I've already got the data in my script.

```
$articleCount = 0;
foreach ($results as $key=>$value) {
    $articleCount + $value['topicCount'];
}
```

Which method is better and why or is there too little difference to care? Is reducing 20,000 SQL requests per day to get a count much of a save?

If I was just counting array items `count($array)` I'd probably take a guess that counting the array was much quicker/less expensive than querying the database - but having to add up totals makes me think there could be a difference, especially if I had 1000 topics with counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost invariably, a second database call will be more of an overhead than doing it in PHP; though you could possibly modify your original MySQL to return a grand total as well as individual topic totals. e.g. using [WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

```
SELECT topicName, 
       COUNT(topicID) AS topicCount
  FROM topicTable 
 GROUP BY topicName 
  WITH ROLLUP
```

should give something like:

```
topicName     | topicCount
--------------|-------------
Latest News   | 101
Events        | 273
...
NULL          | 374
```

For PHP >= 5.5.0, you can improve your foreach loop by using [array_sum()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) instead:

```
$articleCount = array_sum(
    array_column(
        $results,
        'topicCount'
    )
);
```

Comment: Hm.. not sure if this is "improvement". In terms of code readability - it is, but in terms of memory - I doubt

Comment: In terms of memory, it would come down to how many different topic categories there were in the list, but it should be marginally faster than iterating via a foreach() as well

Comment: Yes, and I don't argue with that. Just added note because whole concern is about "performance" (even if OP didn't mentioned which performance he wants to improve)

Comment: Hi @MarkBaker. Thanks for replying. I have PHP 5.3.24 so cannot use `array_column()`. After reading about this function, is possible for me to use `array_sum()` and `array_map` together? Will this have a similar outcome/performance to your suggestion?

Comment: Using [array_reduce()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) would probably be easier than array_sum() and array_map(); but the best performant option would be to do this in your SQL query

Comment: @MarkBaker, thanks. I will try and have a play with ROLLUP later. I'm just confused as to how I would grab the ROLLED-UP count from my DB array. I'm simply putting my query results straight into an array `$topic_list = $STH->fetchAll();`, so not sure how to grab the NULL/count from the array. Maybe I could rebuild my logic by looping through DB records to build the array, and if it comes across a NULL then store that as the count.... not sure.... maybe you could advise. I've accepted your answer anyway as it's been more than helpful.

Comment: The last row of the SQL resultset, corresponding to the last row entry in your array, with a `topicName` of `null` has a `topicCount` value that is the sum of all the previous individual topic counts

Comment: I've got it working using the ROLLUP method and `end($myarray)`. The issue I see with this is where I format this array later on my page, in two places, I will have to filter out the last ROLLUP row, which in turn creates more code. I also think that will be a headache to debug if somebody else has to read my code. Therefore, I feel using `array_sum` and `array_reduce` may be a better option regarding maintenance. Thanks for your input anyway regardless.

Comment: After writing that last message I went back to your proposed method!! Used `ROLLUP` to get the count into my array, used `end($array)` to get the count from end of array, making sure it had the ROLLUP's NULL value, I stored the count and deleted the last item from the array `unset()` so formatting the array later is easier. Thanks.